# Can I have more than one asset catalog in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, asset-catalog, app-thinning

I have a project where I have images.xcassets in my 'copy bundle resources' directory. I want to create a second asset catalog for my 'compile sources' directory because I want the app thinning to split up the classes so the user only downloads what they need. If I do this, I can have up to a 3 mb savings on my bundle. However, I get the error "multiple commands produce Assets.car." Can I have more than one asset catalog? I need separate ones because the classes go in 'compile sources' and not 'copy bundle resources,' or else I would just use a single asset catalog.

Comment: But if the user will download it separately then the resources shouldn’t be part of a bundle and not exist in any assets catalog?

Comment: The user gets the assets stripped out depending on the specification of the asset catalog. Every device and iOS version gets a custom bundle for their device.